# Design a class that can be convertible to/from other libraries

Tags: c++

I wrote a small self-contained library (depends only on the C++ standard library) that has its own built-in 3D vector class:

```
namespace mylibrary {

    struct Vector {
        double x, y, z;

        // and constructors
        // like:
        Vector(double x, double y, double z);

        // and operators
    };

}
```

It's supposed to interact with other code that produces/uses 3D vectors.

Now, assume some other library, which has:

```
namespace otherlibrary {
    struct Vector3 {

        // some different definition

        // And is still able to construct from 3 values
        Vector3(double x, double y, double z);
    };

    doSomething(const Vector3& point); // do something with the point
}
```

This other library could be the plugin API for a 3D modelling tool, or a 3D engine. It also has the concept for a 3D vector, but it's of course a different type than my library's vector, even though the semantics are identical. Think of Python's duck typing: the type doesn't matter as long as it behaves in the expected way.

## Question:

What mechanism could I use to make my library's `Vector` be used conveniently as an argument for `otherlibrary::doSomething()`?

That is, being able to write this:

```
otherlibrary::doSomething( mylibrary::Vector(...) );
```

I can certainly build my `Vector` class to have a templated constructor that accepts any type T with "x, y, z" members, or with `operator[]`, so it can consume almost anything that makes sense to interpret as a 3D vector. Would it be possible to do it the other way around?

## EDIT:

Of course, I could just make it dependent on another library, then I could just reuse the other library's 3D vector abstraction. This is not reasonable, as my library is generic, it makes no sense to, say use Eigen::Vector3d for my vector, as it could then be used in an environment that doesn't use Eigen.

## Best answer:

Based on Neil Kirk's answer:

```
struct Vector {
    using value_type = double;

    template<class T,
             class = typename enable_if<
                 is_constructible<T, value_type,value_type,value_type>::value
                 >::type>
    operator T() const
    {
        return T{x, y, z};
    }
};
```

The `enable_if` i used to resolve ambiguities when multiple overloads functions and operators are available; Eigen is one actual case where it is needed.

Comment: The usual approach is to use free functions with (userdefined) specializations. However, this would really work best, if the library were designed for it, like Boost Fusion, Boost Graph Library etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes add conversion operator to your Vector class.

```
operator otherlibrary::Vector3() const
{
    return otherlibrary::Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

But it means your vector will now depend on the other library..

To avoid dependency, there is no way to do exactly what you are asking. Alternative suggestion is a convert function such as the following, which makes a couple of assumptions about the vector types.

```
template<class T, U>
T ConvertVector3(const U& v)
{
    return T(v.x, v.y, v.z);
}

otherlibrary::doSomething(ConvertVector3<otherlibrary::Vector3>(mylibrary::Vector(x, y, z)));
```

Very verbose though :(

Experimental!! I didn't try this and have no idea if it works. Concern: your vector could convert to any class that takes 3 constructor arguements, even if it doesn't make sense

```
template<class T>
operator T() const
{
    return T(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: And it will imply passing everything by (temp)value. Also, implicit conversions wreak havoc in many cases. I'd consider them evil, but that's a comment to the OP

Comment: I added the explicit detail: I don't want to just go and edit my library every time it is used in a different place.

Comment: @sehe Maybe you like being verbose for no good reason. We are not talking about managed resources here, it's one of the most trivial non-primitive types one could possibly get, a pair/triple of numbers.

Comment: @DanielKO made another edit. IF it works, may be what you want!!

Comment: @DanielKO I don't know what made you assume either of those ("I like being verbose" or "There is no good reason to prefer explicit conversions"). In that fashion, I could assume you don't have a lot of experience in (generic) library design.

Comment: I think these examples would work, but please try them out. For example you could use ideone.com

Comment: @sehe I'm sorry for jumping to conclusions; I had the impression you suggested that implicitly converting between two semantically equivalent and trivial 3D vector types could wreak havoc, which sounds unreasonable.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's probably what I need; I think I'll need to guard it with `enable_if< is_constructible<...> >` though.

Comment: @DanielKO how would that help? If it can't construct it won't compile anyway.

Comment: Also, if the other library implements a complementary converting constructor, the language will flag an ambiguity between using their constructor template or your `operator` template.

Comment: @NeilKirk To avoid overload ambiguities. See [this example](http://ideone.com/nWdmJh). Without the `enable_if` the call becomes ambiguous. This actually happens with Eigen in some places.

Comment: @DanielKO I don't understand why :(

Answer (score 0):

There is seldom a reason to define your own `vector3` type, and this is a serious downside. Even if you do something clever with templates, it can conflict with similar "cleverness" in other libraries.

Define your operators as free functions, not members, and use `std::array` instead. If you really must have your own class, define a `to_array()` function returning the standard type. Any sane library can convert from that, even by using `array::data()` to treat it as a C array.

(Protip: you can `reinterpret_cast` a C-style array to `std::array &` reference and back, to avoid copying data.)