# Easily convert between different geometry classes in c++?

Tags: c++, casting, geometry, ros

I work in robotics, which means I use a large number of open-source projects dealing with 3D geometry. Since the classes and math tend to be fairly simple, everyone seems to implement their own version of Vector3D, Quaternion, etc., each with slight variations, e.g. vec.x, vec.X, vec.x(). So within one project, one might need to convert between Eigen, ROS, Assimp, Bullet, and other versions of the same basic classes. Is there an easy or elegant way to do this in C++ that doesn't require an n^2 mapping from every library to every other library?

Similar to: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092866/design-a-class-that-can-be-convertible-to-from-other-libraries), but I can't edit any of the source libraries.

Example:

```
namespace a
{
class Vector
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
};
} // namespace a

namespace b
{
class Vector
{
public:
    double X, Y, Z;
};
} // namespace b

namespace c
{
class Vector
{
public:
    double& x() { return mx; }
    double& y() { return my; }
    double& z() { return mz; }
private:
    double mx, my, mz;
};
} // namespace c

int main()
{
    a::Vector va;
    b::Vector vb;
    c::Vector vc = va + vb; // Ideal, but probably unrealistic goal
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:
If there are ~10 different geometry libraries, a particular project may only use 2-4 of them, so I'd like to avoid introducing a dependency on all the unused libraries. I was hoping for something like `static_cast<b::Vec>(a::Vec)`, or maybe

```
c::Vec vc = my_cvt<c::Vec>(vb + my_cvt<b::Vec>(va));
```

but my understanding of templates and type_traits is pretty weak.

Comment: Choose an intermediary, and convert to and from that.

Comment: @arprice if you can't change the three of them, consider adding one custom class (a Vector d class) for my answer and it should scale your needs

Answer (score 3):

If you write three helper functions for each vector type to access `X`, `Y` and `Z`:

```
double X(const a::Vector& v) { return v.x; }
double Y(const a::Vector& v) { return v.y; }
double Z(const a::Vector& v) { return v.z; }
double X(const c::Vector& v) { return v.x(); }
double Y(const c::Vector& v) { return v.y(); }
//...
```

then you can easily write template functions that work with any type. e.g:

```
template<typename V1, typename V2>
V1 operator+(const V1& v1, const V2& v2) { 
  return {X(v1)+X(v2), Y(v1)+Y(v2), Z(v1)+Z(v2)};
}

template<typename V1, typename V2>
V1 convert(const V2& v) { 
  return {X(v), Y(v), Z(v)};
}

int main() {
  a::Vector va;
  b::Vector vb;
  auto vc = convert<c::Vector>(va + vb);
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/l1BRYlhlVZ9KoCMH).

Comment: I like this answer! Only the helper functions have to be implemented for each library you want to use and the rest is all templated. However, don't those vectors support `operator[]` -- then the helpers are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just define a `operator+` function and your 'unrealistic goals' would be achieved:

```
c::Vector operator+(const a::Vector& a, const b::Vector& b) {
    return {a.x+b.X, a.y+b.Y, a.z+b.Z};
}
```

And your small code snippet will work.

**EDIT**

If you do not want to define a hell lot of function, and assuming you can't change the Vector version from a and b, modifiy your vector class by adding these constructors:

```
Vector(a::Vector a) : mx(a.x), my(a.y), mz(a.z) {}
Vector(b::Vector b) : mx(b.X), my(b.Y), mz(b.Z) {}
```

And then define only one operator dealing only with the c class:

```
c::Vector operator+(c::Vector a, c::Vector b) {
    return {a.x()+b.x(), a.y()+b.y(), a.z()+b.z()};
}
```

And your code snippet will work with declaring thousands of operator

**EDIT 2**

If you want your type to be compatible with your library's types you may add conversion operator to your struct, example, if you want your type to be convertible with Vector a, add this function inside your class:

```
operator a::Vector() const {
    // return a a::Vector from our c::Vector
    return a::Vector{mx, my, mz};
}
```

Comment: he wants to be able to add the vectors without making n^2 functions to do so.

Comment: Thanks. You may also want to tell OP about the conversion operator, so he can get the library's various types back from his custom type, though that's more speculation on the needs of OP than anything else

Comment: Yes I can easily add this, thanks for the proposition

Comment: I thought OP can't modify any of the vector classes?

Comment: @Chris He's not. This is making his own vector class to convert to and from.

Comment: Defining an intermediary class would certainly drop the number of explicit conversions from O(n^2) to O(n), but I was hesitant to use this method. It introduces a dependency on, and requires prior knowledge of, all geometry classes that will be used by the projects that use the conversion class. This can be solved with judicious use of #ifdef's, but this either introduces include-order issues or requires a list of #define flags to switch on the various libraries. Not a dealbreaker, but I was hoping something with templates or type_traits would be cleaner. I should have mentioned this in-post.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old question but check out Boost QVM.